# Не могу запустить OSGi bundle

Tags: java, maven

Привет! Пытаюсь запустить собранный бандл, но получаю такую ошибку:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: *** Package 'sun.misc' is not imported by bundle org.apache.camel.camel-core [12], nor is there any bundle that exports package 'sun.misc'. However, the class 'sun.misc.Unsafe' is available from the system class loader. There are two fixes: 1) Add package 'sun.misc' to the 'org.osgi.framework.system.packages.extra' property and modify bundle org.apache.camel.camel-core [12] to import this package; this causes the system bundle to export class path packages. 2) Add package 'sun.misc' to the 'org.osgi.framework.bootdelegation' property; a library or VM bug can cause classes to be loaded by the wrong class loader. The first approach is preferable for preserving modularity. ***
at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl$BundleClassLoader.loadClass(BundleWiringImpl.java:2031)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
... 17 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sun.misc.Unsafe not found by org.apache.camel.camel-core [12]
```

Я использую `apache camel`, `camel-mail` и `apache felix plugin`.
Мой `pom.xml` выглядит так:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0              
     http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

     <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

     <groupId>com.camel.mail</groupId>
     <artifactId>com.camel.mail</artifactId>
     <version>1.0</version>

<dependencies>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-mail</artifactId>
    <version>2.17.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-core-osgi</artifactId>
    <version>2.17.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.osgi</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.osgi.core</artifactId>
    <version>6.0.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.osgi.compendium</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.21</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.17</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.21</version>
</dependency>
</dependencies>
    <build>
    <plugins>

    <plugin>
        <inherited>true</inherited>
        <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>osgi-bundle</id>
                <goals>
                    <goal>bundle</goal>
                </goals>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <configuration>
                    <instructions>
                        <Bundle-SymbolicName>${project.artifactId}</Bundle-SymbolicName>
                        <Bundle-Version>1.0</Bundle-Version>
                        <Bundle-Activator>com.camel.mail.Activator</Bundle-Activator>
                        <Import-Package>
                            *;resolution:=optional
                        </Import-Package>
                    </instructions>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

Как я понял из стектрейса, мне нужно добавить пакет `'sun.misc'` в `'org.osgi.framework.system.packages.extra'`, но как это сделать не пойму. Подскажите пожалуйста как решить данную проблему и из-за чего это происходит?

Answer (score 1):

В конфигурационном файле фраймворка( например для Felix это `config.properties`, для Equinox - `config.ini` ) прописать необходимые пакеты в стиле:

```
org.osgi.framework.system.packages.extra=\
 sun.misc,\
 some.package1,\
 some.package2
```

Для Felix знаю дополнительный способ решения: зайти внутрь `felix.jar` и вписать пакеты в `default.properties` под нужной версией Java-машины.

Также почти всегда можно найти необходимую библиотеку и оформить её в OSGi bundle либо прописав манифест вручную, либо перепакетив каким-нибудь сборщиком, либо воспользовавшись спец. утилитами.